# Lost all the software downloaded because of upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.4 lts on a CD so do I upgrade Ubuntu 11.10, but after the upgrade I discovered that all the programs installed on the Ubuntu 11.10 has been deleted. Is it because of the upgrade. And how it has been restored programs???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I write this for everyone else who reads this: 12.04 is in beta testing and is not ready for production use!  It should be installed with the understanding that it contains bugs and some of those might cause very serious problems, including the loss of important files, including programs and data.  It's a very good beta and the bugs are being worked-out quickly, but I'd recommend that if anyone wants to test it, don't upgrade 11.10 but instead put 12.04 onto its own partition.  If your testing involves upgrading 11.10, you should make a full backup first.  (Lest it sound like I represent anyone else, I don't work for Canonical nor am I involved in any way with the development of Ubuntu; I'm just another beta tester.)

Second, however, Yossile is right: your data and the settings for your programs should still be there, so when you reinstall them they should work as you are accustomed.  Unfortunately, it'll take you some time to reinstall them, hopefully not too long.  I hope the process won't be too painful.  I'm sorry this happened.

Comment: Thanks for helping Mr. Kelley. Seems to be working once again to download the software. But not be recovered without re-installing?? Do I have to re-download through software center

Comment: I think downloading through the Software Center might generally be safest, but I guess it depends on what software you need.  If you used PPAs in the past you might have to re-enable some of them.  By the way, a program called Y-PPA-manager (available here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/y-ppa-manager-0084-released-finally.html) has an option to restore PPAs following an upgrade; it might work for you and lessen the amount of work you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade will keep your (and others) home directory but the installed programs will be purged. You will have to reinstall missing programs but the bright side is that the configuration/preferences for each should be there. Those are being kept in your home folder which is still there.

Answer (score 0):

if you did an upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to ubuntu 12.04 it is possible that some applications are not more suported by canonical or been remove from repositories

i did also and upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 2 ubuntu 12.04 beta and the programs where stiil there ..but it could be a change from version for exemple firefox i think it change version is now 11.00 i think in ubuntu 11.10 was 10

but if all your applications has been remove i dont know how it happen unless you made a fresh instalation using a cd or usb

Comment: I boot from cd and I've upgraded from there and after the upgrade has been completed. Found that all the applications that I had been deleted